# Unexpected $end in eval()'d code

Tags: php, eval, syntax-error

I hate to ask such a specific question, but I'm getting an error I can't figure out. This is in a cron job which runs on the hour. I'm creating an array of tasks, each of which has a date check which is supposed to be eval()'d.

```
$todo = array();
$todo[] = array( "date('z')%3 == 0", "Task 1" );
$todo[] = array( "date('N') == 1", "Task 2" );
foreach( $todo as $task )
{
    if( eval($task[0]) ) {
        echo $task[1];
    }
}
```

For some reason the eval() line is giving me this error. **Note that I am getting this error for both tasks.**

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected $end in /file.php(21) : eval()'d code on line 1
```

Any suggestions? I tried searching for this but couldn't find anything. Thank you.

Comment: You're missing a curly brace somewhere. This can't be the whole script.

Comment: I don't see any missing curly braces. The script is working, except for the eval() part.

Comment: If you have PHP >=5.3, you should use anonymous functions instead of eval'd code for your own sanity.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`eval` only accepts statements, not expressions. You need to convert your tests with:

```
if (eval("return $task[0];")) {
```

Comment: Perfect! Worked like a charm! After 20 years of PHP programming it was the first time I've ever needed to use eval()

Answer (score 5):

You are missing ';' on end of string evaluation. Eval function able to process statements or expressions.

Example:

```
$value = 7;
eval("\$value+=2;");
echo $value;
```