# PHP: eval() of a XOR between two strings via the URL parameter

Tags: php

In PHP, the XOR between 2 strings is done by xoring the ascii value of each couple of characters. For instance I can write `"_<(0[|@>2__[@"^":_@_{[([^30|{"` instead of `"echo 'hello';"`.

If I run this PHP `<?php eval("_<(0[|@>2__[@"^":_@_{[([^30|{");`, it prints `hello` on the page. (example in a [sandbox](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/cc18260b4a426f2697795c71bb53dda068a4a7c5))

I tried to `eval` that **XOR in a URL parameter** using the following code running locally at `localhost:8000` but it doesn't print anything.

```php
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['param'])){
        eval($_GET['param']);
        die();
    }
```

The request URL I wrote is:

```
http://localhost:8000/?param="_<(0[|@>2__[@"^":_@_{[([^30|{"
```

My question is why the xor between the strings in the URL parameter is not evaluated. How can I make it working?

Comment: What is the result you are currently getting? And what does `var_dump($_GET['param']);` say?

Comment: In the terminal i get `[Sun Jul  5 23:11:23 2020] PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/index.php(3) : eval()'d code on line 1`. The var_dump is `string(31) ""_<(0[|@>2__[@"^":_@_{[([^30|{"" `.

Comment: You might want to do something like `eval('eval('.$_GET['param'].");");`

Comment: @Progman Great find! Would you mind if I add this to my answer? Or, would you prefer to add it as your own answer?

Comment: Yes, it works! Maybe, as @Muhammad Talha Akbar said, what I've written is not a statement.

Comment: @MuhammadTalhaAkbar Just write it in your answer

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you turn errors `on` in your PHP installation, you would see the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in ... : eval()'d
> code on line 1

Now, on further inspection of the error, I found that `eval()` requires statements and not expressions. See: [Unexpected $end in eval()'d code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6142550/unexpected-end-in-evald-code)

**Since your argument to eval does not contain a statement** ***rather an expression*** `"_<(0[|@>2__[@"^":_@_{[([^30|{"`, **it fails.**

As @Progman suggested in his comment, instead of using:

```
eval($_GET['param']);
```

Use the following:

```
eval('eval('.$_GET['param'].");");
```